# Android - perfomance animation on canvas

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I created simple animation in CustomView to transition beetwen activities. Everything is fine except animation smooth. There are visible lags when circle radius is increased. How can I performance animation to avoid lags?

```
public class CircleAnimationView extends View {

...
public void startAnimation(int x, int y) {
    startX = x;
    startY = y;

    baseAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "baseRadius", 0, maxRadius)
            .setDuration(1000);
    baseAnimator
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    baseAnimator.start();

    finalAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "finalRadius", 0, maxRadius)
            .setDuration(2000);
    finalAnimator
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    if(listener!=null)
        finalAnimator.addListener(listener);
    finalAnimator.start();
}

public void setBaseRadius(final float radius) {
    radiusBase = radius;
    invalidate();
}

public void setFinalRadius(final float radius) {
    radiusFinal = radius;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, radiusBase, basePaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(startX, startY, radiusFinal, finalPaint);
}
};
```

I used view in xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <pl.org.ldi.challenge.views.CircleAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/circle_animation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:base_color="@color/blue"
        app:final_color="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:
I check .trace file from animation, and it looks like that drawing large circle takes too much time - method GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList

Comment: tried to use AnimatorSet to play them together?

Comment: yeah, without diffrence

Comment: tried just one animation?  are you sure that startAnimation() is not called twice or more times?

Comment: just tried, one animation have problem too, little lagging start when radius is greater. I'm sure that startAnimation() is called once (onBackPressed())

Comment: your code looks ok,  do some Log.d with currentTimeMillis inside setFinalRadius()

Comment: Oh, maybe my phone is too weak. http://wklej.org/id/1684654/ http://dropcanvas.com/ltwb4

Comment: its quite nice 90 frames per 2 seconds,  don't you think?

Comment: But circles are glitches :( and after one second, I have 37 frames per seconds. The end is the worst.

Comment: set linear interpolator then and see the result

Comment: LinearInterpolator doesn't help, but I set OvershootInterpolator and reduce time animation, now animation looks not bad (is too fast for human to see glitches)

Answer (score 0):

After set:

```
finalAnimator.setFrameDelay(0);
baseAnimator.setFrameDelay(0);
```

animation looks smoothly. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a handler to call invalidate by help of its postDelayed() method. Call this methods at regular intervals throughout your animations duration. You can calculate the radius according by the ratio of current_time/total_time and multiplied with the maximim radius you want.